# How to delete an item detail from the item list

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an android app using Android Studio and `Kotlin` and managed to create a new field to add more item to a list using tutorials online. I couldn't get the delete button work.

Following is the code for `NewSale.kt`

```
package com.example.trad

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout

class NewSale : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var parentLinearLayout: LinearLayout? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_sale)
        parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout)
    }

    fun deleteItem(view: View) {
        parentLinearLayout!!.removeView(view.parent as View)
    }
    fun addMoreItem(view: View) {
        val inflater =
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val rowView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null)
        parentLinearLayout!!.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout!!.childCount - 1)
    }
}
```

Following is the code for `activity_new_sale.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".NewSale">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etxItemCode"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter Item Code"
                        android:paddingRight="40dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Item description.."
                        android:paddingRight="80dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etxItemquality"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="Pcs" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etxSellPrice"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="Price" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Amt"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteItem"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                        android:onClick="deleteItem" />

                </LinearLayout> 

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddMoreItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:onClick="addMoreItem"
                android:text="Add More Item" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGenerateInvocie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Generate Invoice" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The following code is for `field.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter Item Code"
                        android:paddingRight="40dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Item description.."
                        android:paddingEnd="80dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="Pcs" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="Price" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Amt"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteItem"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                        android:onClick="deleteItem" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I am trying to create is a billing/invoicing part of the app.

I will input items with their price, quantity and calculate item wise amount and calculate the total amount after entering all the items. Then, add it to the firebase database.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am not able to delete an item. I have a function with the name 'deleteItem' and when I hit the delete button nothing happens at all. No errors either.

Comment: You only want to delete the VIew, right? Or you want to remove the item from the database?

Comment: Delete the view only as these items are not inserted into a database yet.

Comment: In that case, it's not a Firebase-related question, right?

Comment: That's true, at this point of time the items are yet to be inserted into Firebase. However, that is my ultimate aim with the app.

Comment: You want to delete the item from RecyclerView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Your feild.xml File with Below Code.  remove Scrollbar to fix extra space issue. I also remove unnecessary linear layout from XML.

```
**feild.xml**
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="40dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Enter Item Code"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Item description.."
                    android:paddingEnd="80dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:hint="Pcs" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:hint="Price" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Amt"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDeleteItem"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                    android:onClick="deleteItem" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly except that I had to add '</LinearLayout>' at the end of it.

Comment: How can I save data that I input in these fields to Firebase Realtime Database? Is this the right way to do it or is there a better way to do what I wanted to do?

Answer (score 2):

Please, change your Function with the below Code. First Get the parent Layout and then remove the child layout from a parent. I suggest you use only one linear layout.

In `NewSal.kt`  Modify Below Function.

```
fun deleteItem(view: View) { 
    val linearParent = view.getParent().getParent().parent as LinearLayout
    val linearChild = view.getParent().parent as LinearLayout
    linearParent.removeView(linearChild) 
}
```

Comment: It worked but I found one issue that if I delete an item from the middle, other items do not move up or down and this creates a blank area. How can we solve this?

Comment: How can I use only one Linear Layout as you have suggested and keep the structure intact?

Comment: @Codist  check my answer. it will help to remove extra space.